# Backbone.js collection.on("add") not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to build a simple resume app. I'm trying to fire off the `add` event when adding an array of models to the collection. The event should simply log in the console that something happened. Unfortunately nothing seems to be happening. Also no error is being logged. Could someone give me a tip?

Here is the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //INITIALIZATION
    var resumeSectionCollection = new ResumeSectionCollection();
    var resumeSectionView = new ResumeSectionView();


    //setting up collection and adding data to it
    resumeSectionCollection.on("add", this.logme,this);
    resumeSectionCollection.add([careerObjectiveModel,workExperienceModel1,workExperienceModel2,workExperienceModel3,educationModel,softwareSkillsModel]);

});
```

Here is the collection class:

```
var ResumeSectionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ResumeSectionModel,  
    logme: function(model){
        console.log("in logme");    
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `$(document).ready` callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
    resumeSectionCollection.on("add", this.logme,this);
    //...
});
```

`this` will, in most cases, be `window` so you're actually saying:

```
resumeSectionCollection.on("add", window.logme, window);
```

But you don't have a `logme` function in `window`, your `logme` function is inside your `ResumeSectionCollection` collection. You probably want something more like this:

```
var ResumeSectionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ResumeSectionModel,  
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('add', this.logme, this);
        // or
        // this.listenTo(this, 'add', this.logme)
    },
    logme: function(model) {
        console.log("in logme");    
    }
});
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var resumeSectionCollection = new ResumeSectionCollection();
    var resumeSectionView = new ResumeSectionView();

    resumeSectionCollection.add([ careerObjectiveModel, workExperienceModel1, workExperienceModel2, workExperienceModel3, educationModel, softwareSkillsModel ]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Is it better to use listenTo than on?

Comment: `listenTo` is preferred because it makes it easier for Backbone to clean up event listeners on its own, if you use `on` then you're always responsible for calling `off` to unbind your listeners.